# How can I retrieve qrcode data from an object?

Tags: java

I have a method that can return QRcode data in `{'p':1,"x":10,"y":20}` this format and it is captured in a variable called `qrdata` (which is a `String` data type ).

My question is how can I retrieve value from that key , value pair object ?
`if .... String qrdata = readQR(image)` then how can I retrieve data from `qrdata` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JSONObject class from javax.json as mentioned in BuildSlayer's answer.

In the example in your question you use simple quotes for 'p'. Assuming it is not a typo and you meant that different charcacters can be used as quotes, you could run into trouble using it though. In that case, you could use plain java to parse your qrData String:

```
public String[] parseJSON(String qrData){
    String[] output = new String[qrData.length()];
    int i = 0;
    for (String keyValuePair:qrData.split(",")) {
        output[i++] = keyValuePair.split(":")[1];
    }
    return output;
}
```

}

Comment: thank u so much! Btw can u explain why the substring is 4?

Comment: First quote is at index 0, key at index 1, second quote at index 2, colon at index 3, so your value starts at index 4. I updated the answer so that it works with multi-characters keys.

Comment: thanks man! Btw I scanned a QR code and the returned value will be like this - { "p" :1 ,"x":10.23,"y":11.2,"z":4.5} 
this is the format given in the programming manual of my work. I am not sure about the type of data. So, basically I need to get the value of x,y and z from that object to know the coordinates of the robot. can I get the values from your given code ?

Comment: My code would return an array of the values from the JSON (in your example, [1,10.23,11.2,4.5] ), so just don't use the first index of the returned array. If you need to return a numeric format, have a look at [Double.parseDouble()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm). If you want to get an output without p straightaway, start iterating from index 1 in the split (using for i = 1 in a for loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(qrData);

System.out.println("p: " + jsonObject.getInt("p"));
System.out.println("x: " + jsonObject.getInt("x"));
System.out.println("y: " + jsonObject.getInt("y"));
```

Output:

```
p: 1
x: 10
y: 20
```